# Difference between quicklz and zlib in Greenplum Database

Tags: compression, greenplum

Hi I am trying to create a table using either quicklz or zlib compression. Which according to you is a better mode of compression? And what are the differences between the two?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't support table compression (except via TOAST, where you don't get a choice of algo). So what are you using? It doesn't seem to be PostgreSQL.

Comment: Hi we used the following code to create a table in PostgreSQL.

CREATE TABLE foo (a int, b text)
WITH (appendonly=true, compresstype=zlib,
compresslevel=5);

We've been able to compress a dummy file of about 1075mb to around 190mb. But the actual file is way too large and we're thinking about what compression type we should use.

Comment: That isn't PostgreSQL. Please run: `SELECT version()` and paste the output. I'd say you're running Greenplum Database, or perhaps using Amazon Redshift (ParAccel).

Comment: Yes in Greenplum database.

Comment: Please don't say "PostgreSQL" when you mean "Greenplum". It's a confusing waste of time for everybody, especially when you're asking about features that only exist in Greenplum or trying to use stuff that was added to later versions of PostgreSQL. It's fine to use the "postgresql" tag, just **always say if you're really using Greenplum**. (The Greenplum folks don't seem to hang out here, try their forums)

Comment: Ok sorry about that. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

In many cases in databases zlib will be better.  Both zlib and gzip compress pretty well though of course the degree of compression with each will depend on your data.  One difference though is that whereas gzip takes approximately the same amount of time to compress as to decompress, zlib will decompress much faster that it compresses.  This makes it good for when you are writing once and reading many times.  Database tables that you are compressing just to save space (or perhaps to improve the effective data I/O rate) will often fit into that pattern.  gzip's properties make it seem well suited for archiving something that you don't expect to access many times.